# Row Number by Certain Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains customer transactions. It looks like this:

[image]

Tha data is sorted by Total Transaction. I want to create a column that contains number by City. For Example, the first row shows City is London so the values is 1, second row becaus it's from London too, the value is also  1. When the Next Row is not London, the value is 2. So it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to create that row number in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `dense_rank()`

```
select *,dense_rank() over(order by city) as cityNumber
from tablename
order by total_transaction desc
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question is valid and as per my understanding on the requirement , you need a two level of `sub query` to get to the final result,

Here I have used `max` as the data first has to be sorted by `Total Transaction` and then we can use `dense_rank` to give a `row number` using the `max value and city.`

```
select t.city as "City"
      ,dense_rank() over (order by max_total_per_city desc,city) as "City Number"
      ,t.customer as "Customer"
      ,t.total_transaction as "Total Transaction"
from
(
select *
      ,max(total_transaction) over (partition by city) as max_total_per_city
  from tableName t
) t
order by total_transaction desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `CityNumber`s with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select City, row_number() over (order by max(TotalTransaction) desc) CityNumber
from tablename 
group by City
```

so you can join the above query to the table:

```
select t.City, c.CityNumber, t.Customer, t.Totaltransaction
from tablename t inner join (
  select City, row_number() over (order by max(TotalTransaction) desc) CityNumber
  from tablename 
  group by City
) c on c.City = t.City  
order by t.TotalTransaction desc
```

Or with `DENSE_RANK()` window function:

```
select t.City,
       dense_rank() over (order by (select max(TotalTransaction) from tablename where City = t.City) desc) as cityNumber,
       t.Customer,
       t.TotalTransaction
from tablename t
order by t.TotalTransaction desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=78b336b261c4fe255b02510939798a66).
Results:

```
> City       | CityNumber | Customer | Totaltransaction
> :--------- | ---------: | :------- | ---------------:
> London     |          1 | Michael  |              250
> London     |          1 | Edward   |              180
> Paris      |          2 | Michael  |              160
> Madrid     |          3 | Luis     |              153
> London     |          1 | Serena   |              146
> Madrid     |          3 | Lionel   |              133
> Manchester |          4 | Frank    |               96
```